# Python numerical integration of data points in polar coordinates

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I want to numerically integrate a set of data points in 3D using scipy. One of the integrals is 
`d(phi)f(x)*cos(phi)` from `0 to 2.pi`, where I have values for f(x) and x can be expressed as a magnitude of 2 vectors **K** and **L** and phi (an angle between these 2 vectors) i.e. `x = sqrt(K^2 + L^2 +2KLcos(phi))` and K will be used in another integral, while L will be kept constant

What I tried so far is scipy.simps:

```
my_Phifunc = np.cos(xnew) * interpol_func
area2=simps(my_Phifunc, xnew)
```

where I have my data points interpolated as interpol_func over an array xnew.

However, this gives me a result far from the expected answer, and I am a little unsure if my thinking is correct here

Comment: The question is kind of confusing. Data points in 3D? x as the magnitude of _two_ vectors, or, wait, an angle? Best try to boil down your problem and edit the post.